# How do you save in Monster Hunter Stories 2?

Tags: monster-hunter-stories-2

When I am roaming the open world doing quests, is there a quick way to save my progress?

The only way I've found is to physically run all the way back to the starting village (Mahana) and visit the bed in my house.

It would be nice to be able to save elsewhere

Comment: Do note that the game has an auto-save as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceed through the initial few story quests until you have the 'Turf War' mission. Completing this and defeating the Yian-Kut Ku will unlock the Catavan.

This service allows saving in the field, at the Catavan, and also fast travel.

Comment: Specifically, it allows saving at the Catavan stations themselves -- which double as the fast travel waypoints.